# How I can retrieve access binded arguments to function

Tags: javascript

I want to get access to arguments binded to function

i.e:

```
var fun = function f(a, b) { console.log(this); console.log(a) };
var inv = fun.bind('dupa', 'value for a');
```

and now I have 'inv' object, There is any way to get access to passed (binded) argumenets from the object ?

Isssue is when I want to invoke 'inv' function passing extra argument for 'b' attribute
inv.call('value for b') ?

Answer (score 0):

> Isssue is when I want to invoke 'inv' function passing extra argument for 'b' attribute inv.call('value for b') ?

To easy:

```
inv("value for b")
```

Call wont work as it sets the context (aka this), and the special function returned by *bind* context is unsettable.